# Python - Dungeon Crawler Game - Moving one place through a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a basic dungeon crawler and I'm having a problem with navigating around the map. I have a map that is stored in a list of lists, like this:

```
map = [
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,0,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

All the 1s stand for rooms, the 0s for walls.

My code to move around the map states a player position as an X,Y coordinate, then passes the map as an argument to a function, using the X,Y coordinates as the index reference. (So Y would be which list to reference, X would be which item in that list)

So my code: states player position on X,Y axis; asks for player input for up, down, left, right by passing the map and X,Y as arguments; checks if an index position + 1 isn't a 0; and then updates the player position accordingly by 1 if it's free. This is the whole thing below:

```
playerPosX = 1
playerPosY = 1

map = [
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,0,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0]
]

def goRight(posX, posY, map):
    if map[posY][posX + 1] == 0:
        print('You can\'t go that way.')
    else:
        posX += 1
    return posX

def goLeft(posX, posY, map):
    if map[posY][posX - 1] == 0:
        print('You can\'t go that way.')
    else:
        posX -= 1
    return posX

def goDown(posX, posY, map):
    if map[posY + 1][posX] == 0:
        print('You can\'t go that way.')
    else:
        posY += 1
    return posY

def goUp(posX, posY, map):
    if map[posY - 1][posX] == 0:
        print('You can\'t go that way.')
    else:
        posY -= 1
    return posY

while True:
    print(playerPosX, playerPosY)
    print('North(n), South(s), West(w), East(e), or Quit(q)?')
    direction = input()
    if direction == 'w':
        playerPosX = goLeft(playerPosX, playerPosY, map)
    elif direction == 'e':
        playerPosX = goRight(playerPosX, playerPosY, map)
    elif direction == 'n':
        playerPosY = goUp(playerPosX, playerPosY, map)
    elif direction == 's':
        playerPosY == goDown(playerPosX, playerPosY, map)
    elif direction == 'q':
        print('Thank you for playing!')
        break
    else:
        print('I didn\'t catch that.')
```

The problem I'm having is that all of the code is working as it should apart from the goDown function. The Y index position of lists isn't incrementing by 1. I added print function that displays the player's position, so you can see it works in every other direction.

Does anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? I'm fairly new to programming so it could be a fundamental error or could even just be a typo. I've been stuck for ages!

Thanks

Comment: In the line you call `goDown`: `playerPosY == goDown(playerPosX, playerPosY, map)`. You mean to use =, not ==.

Comment: As a side note, when you're done you should try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There's a lot of tips you could get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`playerPosY == goDown(playerPosX, playerPosY, map)`

should be

`playerPosY = goDown(playerPosX, playerPosY, map)`

You have an equivalence operator instead of an assignment

Comment: Oh. My. God. I've been staring at this code for hours... Thank you!

Comment: We generally answer simple typo questions with a comment. Such questions normally get closed by community members & auto-deleted by the system since they are of no use to future readers: even if someone has the exact same problem they would be unlikely to find this question via a search. If the question has one or more positive-scored answers that impedes the auto-deletion process.